# Is the composition of a hash function with a block cipher collision resistant?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Assume $H$ is a collision resistant and preimage resistant (unkeyed) hash function and $E(k,y)$ is a block cipher where $k$ is the key.

I am interested into the collision resistance of the composed function $F(k,x)=E(k,H(x))$. A collision for $F$ is defined as $(,)≠(′,′)$ such that $(,)=(′,′)$.

This [post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/96474/36334) seems to say that $F$ should be collision resistant but I can't seem to find a way to formally prove it.

ps:  Could you please indicate which definition of preimage resistance you would use to prove it? As there seems to be multiple ones.

edit: I have changed the formulation from permutation to block cipher. As explained by @poncho, the implication holds for permutation.

Comment: A permutation just arranges the output, it doesn't effect the collision or 1-2 pre-image resistances.

Comment: "You show me two colliding messages in $F$, and I'll show you two colliding messages in $H$"

Comment: A block cipher (for a fixed key) is a permutation, since it needs to be invertible on decryption. So, no change to the answer

Comment: Is F to be understood as a keyed function or would pairs (k,x) and (k',x') such that F(k,x)=F(k',x') be a collision?

Comment: Obviously, you would need to make some assumptions about your block cipher.  If you had $E(k,y) = k \oplus y$, that would make finding collisions easy...

Comment: In practice you'd need a block cipher with a pretty high block size for this to be correct of course. The output of a collision resistant hash function needs to be 256 bit for 128 bit collision resistance. So the block size of the encryption function needs to be 256 bit as large to be a permutation. Not an answer, just an observation; see kodlu's or kelalaka's comment and then poncho's comments to get to the answer.

Comment: @Maeher a collision needs $F(k,x)=F(k',x')$ and $(k,x) \ne (k',x')$

Comment: I don't think the definition of the edit matches the common notion of unkeyed hash if we are to find collisions allowing different keys. In any case,  I think collisions are possible if we "fix the behavior" of the blockcipher/PRP. Given $k, x$, you can simply redifine the outputs for an arbitrary $k'$ so they things collide, and swap the outputs so the blockcipher is still a permutation in $k'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably prove this to be collision-resistant if $E$ is an ideal cipher (and $H$ a random oracle). But it cannot be proven from the simple PRP (SPRP) security of $E$. A simple counterexample is to consider $E$ that ignores the last bit of $k$. Then $(k\|0, x)$ and $(k\|1,x)$ are a collision in your construction.

Comment: You probably mean that $E$ is ignoring the last bit. And if someone tells you that this is contrived, show them almost any implementation of DES and slowly walk away.

Comment: Yes, let me correct $F \leadsto E$ in what I wrote.

Comment: This answer is very interesting. What would happen if E is an ideal cipher and H is only collision resistant and preimage resistant (i.e. not a random oracle).

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the following security experiment: 1) first the *challenger* (not the adversary) picks a key $K$ for $E$ uniformly at random from the key space of the block cipher; 2) the challenger then hands $K$ to the adversary; 3) the experiments ends with the adversary outputting $X$ and $Y$, and it *wins* if $F_K(X) = F_K(Y)$ and $X \neq Y$. Is this a fair interpretation of what you had in mind?

If so, here's a proof showing that $F$ is as collision-resistant as $H$. Suppose $X \neq Y$ are such that $F_K(X) = F_K(Y)$. Let $Z = H(X)$ and $Z' = H(Y)$, so in particular we have $E_K(Z) = E_K(Z')$. But since $E$ is a block cipher (i.e., $E_K(\cdot)$ is a permutation), we must have $Z = Z'$. But this means that $H(X) = H(Y) = Z$. In other words: a collision in $F$ implies a collision in $H$.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But what I had in mind is a little bit different. Finding a collision for F is defined as $(,)=(′,′)$ and $(,)≠(′,′)$.

Answer (score 0):

Under your *non-standard* definition of collision resistance given below, the composition of a hash and block cipher is not collision resistant at all:

> Assume $H$ is a collision resistant and preimage resistant (unkeyed) hash function and $E(k,y)$ is a block cipher where $k$ is the key.

> I am interested into the collision resistance of the composed function $F(k,x)=E(k,H(x))$. A collision for $F$ is defined as $(,)≠(′,′)$ such that $(,)=(′,′)$.

There are *at least* $2^{d+n}$ inputs $(k,x)$ to your function $F(k,x)$ assuming $k$ is $d$ bits long and the cipher blocklength is $n.$ If anything there are many more since a hash function takes inputs that are in general longer than its output bitlength of $n$ bits.

So even under this conservative assumption there are on average $2^d$ inputs that yield the same output. Just by randomly trying different $(k,x)$ pairs you can find a collision in roughly $2^{n/2}$ trials by the birthday paradox regardless of whether $H$ is collision resistant or not.